# how to pick out after using order by?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, rownum

I run:

```
select aname, APERCENT from AGENTS order by APERCENT DESC;
```

and I get this result:

```
ANAME APERCENT

john    7

jane    6

teddy   6

bob     6

allen   5

airon   5
```

Now I want to pick up first column so I add `rownum=1`.

```
select aname, APERCENT from AGENTS order by APERCENT DESC where ROWNUM=1;
```

But SQL command not properly ended, and I want to fix it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add rownum=1 AFTER ordering.
So it will be

```
select *
from
(
select aname, APERCENT 
from AGENTS 
order by APERCENT DESC 
)
where ROWNUM=1;
```

Comment: Should I use subquery? Isn't there another solution?

Comment: With rownum - no. WHERE always evaluates before ORDER BY